# What is the Optimum Cross Entropy Error for Binary Classification

Tags: cross-entropy

Cross Entropy Error is the standard loss function for a number of classification algorithms.

I would like to know what is the optimum cross entropy error I should expect for binary classification?

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited for stats.SE?